# In R ，weighted spearman correlation coefficient code？

Tags: r

Now, I need to do a correlation analysis of the data using weighted spearman. But I only found svycor, which is weighted pearson correlation. So, what is weighted spearman correlation code ?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.